Infer the return type based on a parameter
I've a function that takes an action "DELETE"|"RENAME"|"MOVE"|etc...
I would like the return type to be different depending on the action fired.
For example, "DELETE" should return an object containing "deleteRecursively: boolean".
The remaining actions would return objects with other properties (not in common).
What I've done so far:
type TAction = 'RENAME' | 'DELETE' | 'MOVE';

type DeleteActionResult = { deleteRecursively: boolean };
type RenameActionResult = { newName: string | null };
type MoveActionResult = { newLocation: string | null };

type ActionResult<T extends TAction> = T extends 'DELETE'
    ? DeleteActionResult
    : T extends 'RENAME'
    ? RenameActionResult
    : T extends 'MOVE'
    ? MoveActionResult
    : never;

type TOnAction = <T extends TAction>(action: T, file: File) => Promise<ActionResult<T>>;

const user = { role: "admin" };

const onAction: TOnAction = async (action, file) => {
    switch (action) {
        case 'DELETE': {
            if (user.role === 'admin') {
                    return { deleteRecursively: true }; // NOT INFER
            }
            return {deleteRecursively: false}; // NOT INFER
        }
        case 'RENAME': {
            const newName = window.prompt('Enter new name:', file.name);
            return { newName }; // NOT INFER
        }
        case 'MOVE': {
                    const newLocation = window.prompt('Enter new location:');
            return { newLocation }; // NOT INFER
        }
        default:
            throw new Error('Invalid action');
    }
};


const handleDelete = async (file: File){
   const shouldDeleteRecursively = await onAction("DELETE", file) ?? false;
   await fetch(".../delete", {deleteRecursively: shouldDeleteRecursively });
}

But with this implementation, I got this error:
Type '<T extends TAction>(action: T, file: File) => Promise<DeleteActionResult | RenameActionResult | MoveActionResult>' is not assignable to type 'TOnAction'.
  Type 'Promise<DeleteActionResult | RenameActionResult | MoveActionResult>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ActionResult<T>>'.
    Type 'DeleteActionResult | RenameActionResult | MoveActionResult' is not assignable to type 'ActionResult<T>'.
      Type 'DeleteActionResult' is not assignable to type 'ActionResult<T>'.

The type is well infered when calling the method, but not within the switch case. Do you know if it's possible to do such a thing?

@jcalz just updated the post, I'm gonna look at the link you just sent and will keep you informed. Thanks!

• This is going to look like this question and its answer. • This playground link serves as a demo. Does it fully address the question? If so I'll link that question here. If not, what am I missing?

just use overloads.

Yeah it kinda fully address my question but what if I don't want to have a specific behavior for an action? For example, the "RENAME" one should stay intact and not have a custom implementation? And how can I have autocompletion on the return type? Instead of "knowing" it

@DanielA.White I've already tried overloads (maybe in the wrong way) but it didn't seem to work as expected, would mind showing me an example please?

• "stay intact"? What do you mean?  • You could tell TS that the object is an ActionMap like this playground link shows, which will have TS complain about a bad returned thing, but I don't think autocompletion works with getters.

The actions I'm defining there is to add a certain behavior to the action, but it's not always necessary in some cases. This function should basically be passed to a react component and then will be called when the user presses on a button for example. If "onAction" contains the fired action, then use it to modify the base execution. The example with the "DELETE" action is like so: if the user is an admin, then he can have the choice to delete the folder and its content recursively (by addind a flag in the http request sent to the api). Hope I'm clear enough :p

I don't know anything about react so if that's necessary then I can disengage. I don't see an example in your code where anything is "staying intact" or not being added.  I'd think the onus should probably be on you to make your code a [mre] of what you're asking for. I suspect this might be a followup question and therefore out of scope here, but without a [mre] I'm not sure. Do you want to bring that up as a separate question or [edit] to make this question dependent on it?

The react part is not really necessary there, the function itself could be used with anything. What i mean by "staying intact", is that the "onAction" function could not have an implementation for the "DELETE" action, nor the "RENAME" one either. The actions are just adding a behavior to them, but they aren't required in some cases. So "actionMap" could only contains "MOVE" and that's it.

I've updated the post to add an example with the "handleDelete" method

I'm going to make some guesses that you just want Partial<ActionMap> and that your handleDelete method has typos in it. If I make those changes and refactor I get this version of your code. Does that now fully address the question? Or am I still missing something?

Yeah that's exactly it, thanks a lot!

Currently TypeScript can't do control flow analysis that affects generic type parameters. For example, this means in the case "DELETE" clause inside onAction(), it can narrow the type of action from T to T & "DELETE", but it does absolutely nothing to T itself. So then you try to return a DeleteActionResult but the compiler can't confirm that as a valid ActionResult<T>, since ActionResult<T> is a generic conditional type and that cannot be evaluated without knowing what T is.
There are multiple open feature requests about this, such as microsoft/TypeScript#33014 and microsoft/TypeScript#33912. There is a pull request sitting at microsoft/TypeScript#56941 which might address this, but for now (TypeScript 5.5) you have to work around it.

Right now if you want to do something generic with multiple cases, the only support TypeScript has is to represent it in terms of an indexed access with a generic key.  If you can rewrite things so that you are returning a value of type SomeInterface[K] for generic K, and you can provide a value s of type SomeInterface and a key k of type K, then returning s[k] will be accepted.
Let's rewrite onAction()'s body to be written in terms of indexing into an object of a type related to
interface ActionMap {
    RENAME: RenameActionResult;
    DELETE: DeleteActionResult;
    MOVE: MoveActionResult
}

Now instead of ActionResult<T> we can write ActionMap[T].  In your comments you said you don't want to require onAction() to return a result for every action, so we will write Partial<ActionMap>[T] instead, using the Partial utility type to allow missing properties.  That gives us
type TOnAction =
    <K extends keyof ActionMap>(action: K, file: File) => Promise<Partial<ActionMap>[K]>;

(and I've changed from T to K since this action is acting as a key of our ActionMap interface).
The easiest approach here (especially in light of your desire for autocompletion in IntelliSense) would be to write a helper function that takes an object of functions from actions to results, and creates a TOnAction for us:
const makeOnAction = (
  p: { [K in keyof ActionMap]?: (file: File) => ActionMap[K] | Promise<ActionMap[K]> }
): TOnAction => async (action, file) => await p[action]?.(file)

And now you can make onAction like this:
const onAction = makeOnAction({
    DELETE() {
        if (user.role === 'admin') {
            return { deleteRecursively: true };
        }
        return { deleteRecursively: false }
    },
    RENAME(file) {
        const newName = window.prompt('Enter new name:', file.name);
        return { newName }
    },
    MOVE() {
        const newLocation = window.prompt('Enter new location:');
        return { newLocation }
    }
})

You can verify that TypeScript will infer the return type of each of the DELETE, RENAME, and MOVE methods and autosuggest/autocomplete the keys for you. Note that RENAME() accepts a file parameter because its body needs it.  And let's verify that it can be partial:
const onAction2 = makeOnAction({
    MOVE() {
        const newLocation = window.prompt('Enter new location:');
        return { newLocation };
    }
})

That also works.  And you can call onAction or onAction2 like
const handleDelete = async (file: File) => {
    const shouldDeleteRecursively = 
      await onAction("DELETE", file) ?? { deleteRecursively: false };    
}

and verify that onAction("DELETE", file) returns a DeleteActionResult | undefined, and therefore that shouldDeleteRecursively is a DeleteActionResult.
Playground link to code
